# Performance of DGEMM with f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, blas, f2py

I tried to wrap `dgemm` in `fortran` via `f2py` and comparing the time. Looks like `dgemm` is much slower (a factor of 10) than `numpy-einsum` in small dimension matrices. The timer of `dgemm` is inside `fortran` code. I think a pure `fortran` `dgemm` will be much faster.  Why? I think `numpy` wraps C, so both `numpy` and `f2py` would have loading time to compile languages.

python part

```
import numpy as np
import test_fortran
import time

dim_n = 10
A = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
B = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
C = np.zeros((dim_n, dim_n))

A = np.asfortranarray(A)
B = np.asfortranarray(B)
C = np.asfortranarray(C)

start = time.time()
test_fortran.wrap(A, B, C)
end = time.time()
print("Fortran time:", end - start)
#print(C)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
start = time.time()
C_check = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
end = time.time()
print("Numpy einsum time:", end - start)
#print(C_check)

# Compare the two results
print("Are the results equal?")
print(np.allclose(C, C_check))
```

`Fortran` part

```
module types

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6,37) ! single precision
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307) ! double precision
    
    !real(sp) :: r_sp = 1.0
    !real(dp) :: r_dp = 1.0_dp
    
end module


subroutine wrap(A, B, C)

    use types
    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64

    real(dp), intent(in) :: A(:, :), B(:, :)
    real(dp), intent(inout) :: C(:, :)
    real(dp) :: alpha, beta
    integer :: m, n, p !, start, finish, rate 
    Integer(li) :: start, finish, rate

    alpha = 1.0_dp
    beta = 0.0_dp

    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)
    p = size(B, 2)

    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', m, p, n, alpha, A , m, B , n, beta, C, m )

    Call System_clock( finish, rate )
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for dgemm', Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
   ! C = matmul(A, B)
end subroutine wrap
```

using `python -m numpy.f2py -c  --f90flags='-O3 -lopenblas'  -m test_fortran test_fortran.f90`. I got

```
  Time for dgemm   9.6337000000000002E-003
Fortran time: 0.010259628295898438
Numpy einsum time: 0.00018858909606933594
Are the results equal?
True
```

Updated:
(1)
for larger dimension, results would change. E.g.,
`n=100`,

```
 Time for dgemm   1.1398200000000001E-002
Fortran time: 0.011998414993286133
Numpy einsum time: 0.0005433559417724609
Are the results equal?
True
```

`n=1000`

```
 Time for dgemm   6.8635000000000002E-002
Fortran time: 0.06942296028137207
Numpy einsum time: 0.6464102268218994
Are the results equal?
True
```

(2)
and replacing `matmul` for `dgemm` in `fortran` part would greatly speed up in smaller dimensions
`n=10`

```
 Time for dgemm   1.7999999999999999E-006
Fortran time: 0.0011439323425292969
Numpy einsum time: 0.00012946128845214844
Are the results equal?
True
```

`n=100`

```
 Time for dgemm   4.7909999999999999E-004
Fortran time: 0.0011742115020751953
Numpy einsum time: 0.000514984130859375
Are the results equal?
True
```

`n=1000`

```
 Time for dgemm  0.12110920000000000
Fortran time: 0.12291121482849121
Numpy einsum time: 0.6383745670318604
Are the results equal?
True
```

(3) However, the problem is not entirely the overhead of calling `dgemm` I think, unless there are multiple call issue (f2py->fortran->blas)
For example, the following pure Fortran code to do `dgemm`

```
Program test_dgemm

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  
   ! Implicit None
  
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: b
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c
  
    Integer :: na, nb, nc, m_iter
    Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
    real(dp) :: sum_time1, alpha, beta


    
    Write( *, * ) 'na, nb, nc?'
    Read( *, * ) na, nb, nc
    Allocate( a ( 1:na, 1:nb ) ) 
    Allocate( b ( 1:nb, 1:nc ) )  
    Allocate( c( 1:na, 1:nc ) )
  
  
    Call Random_number( a )
    Call Random_number( b )
    c  = 0.0_dp
 
    alpha = 1.0_dp
    beta = 0.0_dp
    m_iter = 100
  
    write (*,*) 'm_iter average', m_iter 

    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    do m = 1, m_iter     
      Call System_clock( start, rate )
      Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, nc, nb, alpha, a , na,  b , nb, beta, c, na )
      Call System_clock( finish, rate )
      sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    end do  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for dgemm', sum_time1 / m_iter
  End
```

provides

```
 na, nb, nc?
10 10 10
 m_iter average         100
 Time for dgemm   1.5866999999999999E-005
```

Updated 2: as suggested in the comment, if I recall/only iter once in pure Fortran, I can see speed difference and `scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm` is faster (the fortran part with f2py added explicit dimension, did not include updated one, since the post may be too long)

```
import numpy as np
import test_fortran
import time
import scipy.linalg #from . import linalg

dim_n = 10
A = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
B = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
C = np.zeros((dim_n, dim_n))

A = np.asfortranarray(A)
B = np.asfortranarray(B)
C = np.asfortranarray(C)

start = time.time()
test_fortran.wrap(A, B, C, dim_n, dim_n, dim_n)
end = time.time()
print("Fortran time:", end - start)

start = time.time()
test_fortran.wrap(A, B, C, dim_n, dim_n, dim_n)
end = time.time()
print("Fortran time:", end - start)

#print(C)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
start = time.time()
C_check = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
end = time.time()
print("Numpy einsum time:", end - start)
#print(C_check)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
start = time.time()
C_check = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
end = time.time()
print("Numpy einsum time:", end - start)
#print(C_check)


# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
start = time.time()
C2_check = scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm(1.0, A, B) #np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
end = time.time()
print("Numpy scipy-einsum time:", end - start)
#print(C_check)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
start = time.time()
C2_check = scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm(1.0, A, B) #np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
end = time.time()
print("Numpy scipy-dgemm time:", end - start)
#print(C_check)

# Compare the two results
print("Are the results equal?")
print(np.allclose(C, C_check))
print(np.allclose(C, C2_check))
```

get

```
 Time for dgemm   1.1372600000000000E-002
Fortran time: 0.012313604354858398
 Time for dgemm   1.4800000000000001E-005
Fortran time: 0.0016214847564697266
Numpy einsum time: 0.00011920928955078125
Numpy einsum time: 2.7894973754882812e-05
Numpy scipy-einsum time: 7.319450378417969e-05
Numpy scipy-dgemm time: 1.5974044799804688e-05
Are the results equal?
True
True
```

Update3
If I remove the timer part in Fortran and using explicit dimension, everything works
`n=10`

```
Fortran time: 0.011441946029663086
Fortran time: 3.218650817871094e-05
Fortran time: 9.298324584960938e-06
Numpy einsum time: 0.00010418891906738281
Numpy einsum time: 2.1696090698242188e-05
Numpy scipy-einsum time: 5.364418029785156e-05
Numpy scipy-dgemm time: 1.2159347534179688e-05
Are the results equal?
True
True
```

`n=100`

```
Fortran time: 0.01060938835144043
Fortran time: 7.772445678710938e-05
Fortran time: 7.200241088867188e-05
Numpy einsum time: 0.0005977153778076172
Numpy einsum time: 0.0005030632019042969
Numpy scipy-einsum time: 0.0001475811004638672
Numpy scipy-dgemm time: 0.00021791458129882812
Are the results equal?
True
True
```

`n=1000`

```
Fortran time: 0.06519079208374023
Fortran time: 0.08363509178161621
Fortran time: 0.06780505180358887
Numpy einsum time: 0.6771063804626465
Numpy einsum time: 0.8117749691009521
Numpy scipy-einsum time: 0.08512425422668457
Numpy scipy-dgemm time: 0.0717315673828125
Are the results equal?
True
True
```

Comment: It is completely normal that BLAS calls are slow for very small matrices. There is overhead involved in the calls. What is the performance for large matrices? Try also comparing `dgemm` and native `matmul` in Fortran for such small matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For larger matrices, the difference will be smaller (call `dgemm`). Using `matmul` will let the f2py python fortran much faster for small dimension indeed. But, if I use complete Fortran, `dgemm` is ~1e-5 second for `n=10` matrices. `dgemm` is not bad for smaller dimensino in pure Fortran. I will update the question soon.

Comment: There is still a lot that can be optimized. Try remove all unnecessary clutter from `wrap`. Try to switch from assumed shape arrays like `a(:)` to explicit size `a(na,nb)`. Look how `dgemm` is wrapped inside numpy itself for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm.html  Test also the performance of this one and look inside the source code to see how they do it.

Comment: Given explicit dimension does not help much. Thanks I don't know `scipy` used `f2py`, thought it is similar to `numpy` loads `C`. Will test it.

Comment: Your last test with `miter` calls to `dgemm` looks a bit contradictory with your initial test. What do you obtain with `m_iter=1`?Is it possible that in the Python wrap there is a kind "cold start" for `dgemm` (for example being dynamically loaded at execution)? Can you try calling twice the wrapped code from Python, and see if the second call is faster?

Comment: Thanks. I thought "cold start" is more relevant to JIT type of language like `julia` and does not affect Fotran/Python. Actually second call helps a lot! Though still slower than `scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm`, means there is a smarter way of doing so (will update the question)

Comment: Once I removed the timer and printing, `f2py` fortran and scipy results got similar. Thank you all! will update the question!

Comment: You can also put the findings into an answer if you think it answers your question sufficiently.

Comment: I think that "cold starts" can also apply to traditionally compiled languages, when dynamic libraries are used. Typically the binary code of the library is loaded only when needed. There can also exists some hardware related cold starts, for instance if the CPU is in a kind a idle state with reduced frequency, it can take a bit of time to revert to the nominal frequency and/or to the turbo frequency.